# Load .npz from a HTTP link

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, wget

I use a web service to train some of my deep learning models through a Jupyter Notebook on AWS. For cost reasons I would like to store my data as `.npz` files on my own server and load them straight to memory of my remote machine.

The `np.load()` function doesn't work with `http` links and using `urlretrieve` I wasn't able to make it work. I only got it working downloading the data with `wget` and then loading the file from a local path. However, this doesn't fully solve my problem.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that if the first argument of `np.load` is a file-like object, it has to be `seek`-able:

> `file` : file-like object, string, or pathlib.Path The file to read.
>   File-like objects must support the seek() and read() methods. Pickled
>   files require that the file-like object support the readline() method
>   as well.

If you are going to serve those files over `http` and your server supports the `Range` headers, you could employ the implementation (Python 2) presented in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7852229/5351549) for example as:

```
F = HttpFile('http://localhost:8000/meta.data.npz')
with np.load(F) as data:
    a = data['arr_0']
    print(a)
```

Alternatively, you could fetch the entire file, create an in-memory file-like object and pass it to `np.load`:

```
from io import BytesIO
import numpy as np
import requests

r = requests.get('http://localhost:8000/meta.data.npz', stream = True)
data = np.load(BytesIO(r.raw.read()))
print(data['arr_0'])
```